# Combine multiple fragments in another with GraphQL

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

I'm learning Angular with GraphQL and I've some difficulties.

I need to combine several fragments in another but I don't know how to do it.

```
export type User = {
    id: string;
    name: number;
}

export type Cart = {
    productId: string;
    product: string;
    price: number;
}

export type UserInfo = {
    id: string;
    name: number;
    productId: string;
    product: string;
    price: number;
}

const FRAGMENT_USER = gql`
    fragment fragmentUser on User {
        id
        name
    }
`;

const FRAGMENT_CART = gql`
    fragment fragmentCart on Cart {
        productId
        product
        price
    }
`;

const FRAGMENT_USER_INFO = gql`
    fragment fragmentUserInfo on UserInfo {
        ...fragmentUser
        ...fragmentCart
    }
`;
```

When I use this code in browser, Apollo return an error.